# Google Play Services Activity Recognition - Battery use?

Tags: android, google-play-services, battery

Is the Google Play Services component *always* determining the user's current activity, or only when an app is connected to receive activity updates? The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) isn't really clear about this, it just says that it has a minimal battery impact in general. I'd like to know if an app constantly querying the user's current activity (with a 2-minute interval, for example) would put any additional strain on the user's battery or not.

Comment: That's new enough that you may need to run your own experiments. It's also possible that it will vary some by device, as sensor power consumption probably varies.

Comment: I remember watching the keynote in Moscone and I think Hugo said something around 1% every hour or so. Maybe that can give you some small direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The battery cost is based on the interval the app specifies. So if you request a 2 minute interval, the device will sleep for 2 minutes, wake-up for a few seconds to do an activity recognition and then go back to sleep for another 2 minutes. Intervals of 2 or 3 minutes should have a minimal battery impact.